# MS-SQL max ID with inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can't see the wood for the trees on this and I'm sure it's simple.
I'm trying to return the max ID for a related record in a joined table

Table1

| NiD | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Peter |
| 2 | John |
| 3 | Arthur |

Table2

| ID | NiD | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 3 | 10 |
| 4 | 1 | 20 |
| 5 | 2 | 15 |

Max Results

| NiD | ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 20 |
| 2 | 5 | 15 |
| 3 | 3 | 10 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I'd do it, I think `ID` and `Value` will be `NULL` when Table2 does not have a corresponding entry for a Table1 record:

```
SELECT NiD, ID, [Value]
FROM Table1
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 ID, [Value]
    FROM Table2
    WHERE Table1.NiD = Table2.NiD
    ORDER BY [Value] DESC
) AS Top_Table2
```

Comment: thanks, that worked a charm, slightly mod'd to use inner join as other tables are dependant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` for this:

```
select NiD, ID, Value
from (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by NiD order by ID desc) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
where seqnum = 1;
```

As the question is stated, you do not need `table1`, because `table2` has all the ids.

Comment: If you need the names, modify Gordon's SQL to replacing `t2` with `t2 INNER JOIN table1 ON t2.nid = table1.nid` and update the select list to reflect what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Names
(
    NID INT,
    [Name] VARCHAR(MAX)
)

CREATE TABLE Results
(
    ID INT,
    NID INT,
    VALUE INT
)

INSERT INTO Names VALUES (1,'Peter'),(2,'John'),(3,'Arthur')
INSERT INTO Results VALUES (1,1,5),(2,2,10),(3,3,10),(4,1,20),(5,2,15)

SELECT  a.NID,
        r.ID,
        a.MaxVal
FROM    (
            SELECT  NID,
                    MAX(VALUE) as MaxVal
            FROM    Results r
            GROUP BY NID
        ) a
        JOIN Results r
            ON a.NID = r.NID AND a.MaxVal = r.VALUE
ORDER BY NID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have used in similar situations, performance was fine, provided that the data set wasn't too large (under 1M rows).

```
SELECT 
    table1.nid
    ,table2.id
    ,table2.value
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.nid = table2.nid
WHERE table2.value = (
    SELECT MAX(value)
    FROM table2
    WHERE nid = table1.nid)
ORDER BY 1
```